# Unmatched fields when listing rows in Bigquery API Python with selected_fields

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to read a selected fields of a table in Bigquery with the Python API.

This is my code:

```
rows = bigquery_client.list_rows(table_ref,
                selected_fields=[bigquery.SchemaField('id', 'INTEGER'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('name', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('short_name', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('subdomain', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('address', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('address2', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('department', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('city', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('state', 'STRING'),
                bigquery.SchemaField('zip', 'STRING')])
for row in rows:  # API request
        print(row)
```

And I;m getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data 'dummy' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

This dummy value comes from subdomain field, that is marked as String, so I don't understand why Bigquery is parsing it as DateTime. I have checked that the table is well created, so this is not the problem.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using this:

```
# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query = """SELECT id, name, short_name,
    subdomain, address, address2, department, state, zip
    from dataset.table;"""

query_job = bigquery_client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
```